# Django renders template blocks in wrong order

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a problem with rendering templates in Django. Blocks don't seem to appear in the DOM position they were defined in. Here is my code:

I'm using a base template (**base.html**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Partwell Transactional Email</title>
        <style>
        ...
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="preheader">Partwell email</span>
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                        <div class="content-main">
                            {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
                            {% block content_extended %} {% endblock content_extended %}
                        </div>
                        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                        {% block unsubscribe %} {% endblock unsubscribe %}
                        <!-- START FOOTER -->
                        <div class="footer">
                            <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="content-block">
                                        {% block behalf %} {% endblock behalf %}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <br />
                                    <span class="apple-link">********Amtsgericht Charlottenburg *********</span>
                                    <span class="apple-link">&nbsp;*****</span>
                                    <br />
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END FOOTER -->
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a template that extends the base template. This template is also a base template for all transactional emails (**tenant-base.html**):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block behalf %}
    This email was sent on behalf of {{ tenant.name }}.
{% endblock behalf %}
```

Ultimately, I'm using the tenant-base.html to create the final template:

```
{% extends "tenant-base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main">
        <tr>
            [...]
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

The final result looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the `behalf` block was rendered lower than it was originally defined. It is not the last line defined in the template, yet it moves down in the dom. I'm seeing this behavior with other blocks too. I would love to know why this happens and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Django template problem but happens because one of your `<tr>...</tr>` has no `<td>...</td>` inside.

If I change your footer to this it works:

```
<div class="footer">
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="content-block">
                {% block behalf %} {% endblock behalf %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <span class="apple-link">********Amtsgericht Charlottenburg *********</span>
                <span class="apple-link">&nbsp;*****</span>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

(Please note the added `<td>...</td>` in the second table row.)

Comment: Thanks! That was a big help!